# How to pass an object to a view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, object, view, laravel-5

I want to pass an object of Student Model to a view in Laravel. I tried using

```
return view('student/main')->with($student);
```

Where $student is a instance of Student Model (Code is below)

But it gave an error "Illegal offset type"

I know that data can be passed as an array to a view. But I really want to pass it as a object if possible. Then I can display data as follows by fetching data from get methods.

```
<h4 class="text-left"><strong>{{$student->getName()}}</strong> </h4>
```

I am looking for a solution which can be done using keeping objects instead of arrays.(if possible)

The Student model code is as follows. It consists with simply setters and getters.

```
class Student extends Model{

//attributes

private $student_id;
private $first_name;
private $last_name;
private $batch_id;

// set attributes

public function setID($student_id)
{
    $this->student_id = $student_id;
}

public function setFirstName($first_name)
{
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
}

public function setLastName($last_name)
{
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
}

public function setBatchID($batch_id)
{
    $this->batch_id = $batch_id;
}

// get attributes

public function getName()
{
    return $this->first_name." ".$this->last_name;
}

public function getID()
{
    return $this->student_id;
}

public function getBatchID()
{
    return $this->batch_id;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to name your variable:

```
return view('student/main')->with(['student' => $student]);
```

Answer (score 5):

You've got a number of options to do that

```
return view('student/main', ['student'=> $student]);

return view('student/main', compact('student'));

return view('student/main')->with('student', $student);

return view('student/main')->withStudent($student);
```